# How do I sort a master table based on metadata in a separate table in MySQL 5.5.x?

Tags: mysql, sorting, left-join, metadata

I'm hoping to get some advise on an SQL problem...

We have a master table (MySQL 5.5.x) that contains very little information.  We we also have a metadata table that stores variable/value pairs and references the master table.  The issue I'm having is that we need to retrieve the information using a JOIN to combine both tables, but we need to sort the output based on a particular meta-datum.  The following trivial example will illustrate.

Here's a super-distilled version of the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE fundraise (
  id        INTEGER NOT NULL,
  charity   TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE meta (
  master_id INTEGER REFERENCES fundraise(id),
  variable  TEXT NOT NULL,
  value     TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

We then enter some information for all three charities:

```
INSERT INTO fundraise(id, charity) VALUES
  (1, 'save the dolphins'),
  (2, 'feed the kids'),
  (3, 'cloth the homeless');
```

We also insert some metadata:

```
INSERT INTO meta(master_id, variable, value) VALUES
  (1, 'name',   'Mike'), (1, 'priority', 'high'),     (1, 'start','2016'),
  (2, 'name',   'Barb'), (2, 'priority', 'veryhigh'), (2, 'start','2012'),
  (3, 'name',   'Sam'),  (3, 'priority', 'veryhigh'), (3, 'start','2013');
```

Note that the metadata variable 'start' is intended to be used as the sort order of the required report.  Here's the SQL statement I'm using to generate the report (unsorted):

```
SELECT   f.charity, m.variable, m.value
FROM     fundraise f 
LEFT OUTER JOIN meta m ON (f.id = m.master_id);
```

The output I'm getting seems correct, for the most part, except that we haven't sorted yet:

```
+--------------------+----------+----------+
| charity            | variable | value    |
+--------------------+----------+----------+
| save the dolphins  | name     | Mike     |
| save the dolphins  | priority | high     |
| save the dolphins  | start    | 2016     |
| feed the kids      | name     | Barb     |
| feed the kids      | priority | veryhigh |
| feed the kids      | start    | 2012     |
| cloth the homeless | name     | Sam      |
| cloth the homeless | priority | veryhigh |
| cloth the homeless | start    | 2013     |
+--------------------+----------+----------+
```

But what I really need is for it to display sorted on the "start" year, while keeping all the details about a particular charity together.  In other words, I need to see the report order by year, like this:

```
+--------------------+----------+----------+
| charity            | variable | value    |
+--------------------+----------+----------+
| feed the kids      | name     | Barb     |
| feed the kids      | priority | veryhigh |
| feed the kids      | start    | 2012     |
| cloth the homeless | name     | Sam      |
| cloth the homeless | priority | veryhigh |
| cloth the homeless | start    | 2013     |
| save the dolphins  | name     | Mike     |
| save the dolphins  | priority | high     |
| save the dolphins  | start    | 2016     |
+--------------------+----------+----------+
```

But I'm at a loss as to how to do this... Anyone has any suggestions on how to do this using SQL, exclusively?!?!

May thanks in advance!

p.s., I'd like to point out that the actual system I'm using is much much more complex, and the above is a rather contrived demo to simplify the asking of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT  f.id AS id,f.charity, m.variable, m.value FROM     fundraise f  RIGHT OUTER JOIN meta m ON (f.id = m.master_id) GROUP BY value HAVING (variable = 'start') ORDER BY value) as sorted_table LEFT JOIN meta m2 ON sorted_table.id = m2.master_id ORDER BY sorted_table.value
```

This is my result using that query.

```
MariaDB [fbb]> SELECT * FROM (SELECT  f.id AS id,f.charity, m.variable, m.value FROM     fundraise f  RIGHT OUTER JOIN meta m ON (f.id = m.master_id) GROUP BY value HAVING (variable = 'start') ORDER BY value) as sorted_table LEFT JOIN meta m2 ON sorted_table.id = m2.master_id ORDER BY sorted_table.value
    -> ;
+------+--------------------+----------+-------+-----------+----------+----------+
| id   | charity            | variable | value | master_id | variable | value    |
+------+--------------------+----------+-------+-----------+----------+----------+
|    2 | feed the kids      | start    | 2012  |         2 | name     | Barb     |
|    2 | feed the kids      | start    | 2012  |         2 | priority | veryhigh |
|    2 | feed the kids      | start    | 2012  |         2 | start    | 2012     |
|    3 | cloth the homeless | start    | 2013  |         3 | name     | Sam      |
|    3 | cloth the homeless | start    | 2013  |         3 | priority | veryhigh |
|    3 | cloth the homeless | start    | 2013  |         3 | start    | 2013     |
|    1 | save the dolphins  | start    | 2016  |         1 | name     | Mike     |
|    1 | save the dolphins  | start    | 2016  |         1 | priority | high     |
|    1 | save the dolphins  | start    | 2016  |         1 | start    | 2016     |
+------+--------------------+----------+-------+-----------+----------+----------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [fbb]>
```

Comment: that's a very interesting approach.  I'll study it and attempt to apply it to the actual code.  Many thanks!